# Correctness of Code of a Leetcode problem: container with most water

Tags: python, proof-of-correctness

This is a problem in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/description/

> You are given an integer array height of length n. There are n vertical lines drawn such that the two endpoints of the ith line are (i, 0) and (i, height[i]).
>
> Find two lines that together with the x-axis form a container, such that the container contains the most water.
>
> Return the maximum amount of water a container can store.

This is the code that I wrote:

```py
class Solution:
    def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
        maxvol = 0
        lo = 0
        hi = len(height)-1
        while lo < hi:
            vol = (hi-lo)*min(height[lo],height[hi])
            if maxvol < vol: maxvol = vol
            if height[lo] < height[hi]:
                lo += 1
            else:
                hi -= 1
        return maxvol
```

My question is correctness of the code. There are two indices running `lo` and `hi`, so I am trying to set up an induction hypothesis on these two indices:

IH: for any `i <= lo` and `j >= hi`, `vol(i,j) <= maxvol`, where `vol(i,j)` is volume formed by `i`th and `j`th index of `height`.

Base case is trivial, so I shall assume that IH is correct for some index `lo` and `hi`. Suppose `height[lo] < height[hi]`, so `lo = lo+1`. There shall be `maxvol` corresponding to two indices `lo` and `hi`.

Now, I need to prove that: for all `i <= lo` and `j >= hi`, `vol(i,j) <= maxvol`. The problem arises when `i = lo`. I know that `vol(lo',hi) <= maxvol` and `maxvol <= maxvol`, but how can I successfully assert that `vol(lo,j) <= maxvol` for all `j >= hi`?